# Is ADFS 2.0 compatible with .Net 4.5?

Tags: compatibility, .net-4.5, adfs2.0

I need to install .Net 4.5 on a ADFS 2.0 server  (both proxy and server)

Before I do, can anyone confirm if ADFS is compatible with .net4.5?